# Why did the % answered dropped from 74% to 63% yesterday?

Tags: discussion, stats

Unless my memory tricks me, a few days ago  the % answered was around 74%, and the next it drops to 63%. Any reason why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was [a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233987/215468) in the algorithm that calculates `IsAnswered`. That field is used to calculate the % answered value.

The bug is now gone as of two days ago:

> I've updated the query to check for nulls on the IsAnswered field - this will be deployed in the next build (rev 2014.6.16.1659, meta rev 2014.6.16.2312).
>
> The query runs on a daily schedule, so may be a day or two before it kicks off.

(from [Oded's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234080/215468))

Since this was fixed, our % answered is now... correct.

Comment: I assumed that the 74% was correct but using a different algorithm (since I could see the stats here didn't agree with that).

Comment: Could also be that Nicolas and Frank ask too many too difficult questions, which confused the stats, which in turn dropped...? #D

Comment: I want to create 50 very difficult (yet valid) questions per day, is there an app that can generate these 50 questions automatically for me? Open source, in Haskell, runs on z/OS.